# How to convert the node value to Integer

Tags: groovy

I tried to write a groovy script which reads the value from response xml

when value was read it was read in the format [001] but i require that to be read without braces how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

So, that's a list. Try grabbing the first element

```
value[ 0 ] as Integer
```